# how to apply on click toast using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I am stuck in a problem related to JavaScript, How to apply the toast.

I want help in apply the on click toast using JavaScript, but the toast have to came only when the given condition is not true, if the given condition if true then the page will work without that toast.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to make a toast when the entered e-mail is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of conditional statments & DOM Manipulation check this sample code you can change based on you design. you can use javascript plugin like toastrjs,carlosroso.com/notyf/

```
function showToast(message) {
      // Create a toast div element
      const toast = document.createElement('div');
      toast.classList.add('toast');
      toast.innerText = message;
    
      // Append the toast to the body
      document.body.appendChild(toast);
    
      // Set a timeout to remove the toast after a certain period
      setTimeout(() => {
        toast.remove();
      }, 3000); // Toast will be automatically removed after 3 seconds
    }
    
    function handleClick() {
      // Your condition
      const condition = false;
      
      if (!condition) {
        // Call the showToast function with the desired message
        showToast('Oops, something went wrong!');
      }
    
      // Rest of your click event logic goes here
      // ...
    }
    
    // Attach the handleClick function to your button's click event
    const button = document.getElementById('your-button-id');
    button.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
```

I hope this will solve your problem.